# Magento2 setValue() of a text field in System.xml

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I've created a configuration screen for my Magento2 module, on this file (System.xml) I've an input text field like following:

```
<field id="postback_url" type="text"...>
     <backend_model>Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\Configs<backend_model>
</field>
```

I need to insert a default value. This value will the BaseUrl + /some-endpoint

How do I insert a default value on my text field? 
i'm not quite sure how it can be done in Magento2.x
In magento 1.x I've used this:

```
class myClassName extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data{
    protected function _afterLoad(){
       $this->setValue("my URL goes here");
    }
```

But apparently, it doesn't work on Magento 2.x

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a dynamic value, for example, to get a dynamic value inside the comment and /comment, you should use something like Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\ConfigCommentin the model class and then in class Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\ConfigComment.php

```
class ConfigComment implements \Magento\Config\Model\Config\CommentInterface
{

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
      $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
  }


  public function getCommentText($elementValue)
  {
     $baseurl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
     return $baseurl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your modules etc folder create a config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <yoursectionid>
            <yourgroupid>
                <yourfieldid>somevalue</yourfieldid>
            </yourgroupid>
        </yoursectionid>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your time on answering me! How can I add a dynamic value? For example, get the base url of the store?

Comment: OK, that is a good question, I will come back with this answer soon.